# Replace all unquoted characters from a file bash

Tags: bash, replace

Using bash, how would one replace all unquoted characters from a file?

I have a system that I can't modify that spits out CSV files such as:

```
code;prop1;prop2;prop3;prop4;prop5;prop6  
0,1000,89,"a1,a2,a3",33,,  
1,,,"a55,a10",1,1 L,87  
2,25,1001,a4,,"1,5 L",
```

I need this to become, for a new system being added

```
code;prop1;prop2;prop3;prop4;prop5;prop6  
0;1000;89;a1,a2,a3;33;;  
1;;;a55,a10;1;1 L;87  
2;25;1001;a4;1,5 L;
```

If the quotes can be removed after this substitution happens in one command it would be nice :) But I prefer clarity to complicated one-liners for future maintenance.

Thank you

Comment: You want to remove " and replace , with ;?

Comment: @MarounMaroun that's optimistic since the separator can appear in strings. This is typical parsing work. I'm not familiar with a good method to parse csv with shell tools.

Comment: I just edited it - I need to first replace the unquoted , then get rid of the ; so that the commas that were quoted initially stay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
sed -e 's/,/;/g' -e ':loop; s/\("\)\([^;]*\);\([^"]*"\)/\1\2,\3/; t loop'
```

**Test:**

```
$ sed -e 's/,/;/g' -e ':loop; s/\("\)\([^;]*\);\([^"]*"\)/\1\2,\3/; t loop' yourfile
code;prop1;prop2;prop3;prop4;prop5;prop6  
0;1000;89;"a1,a2,a3";33;;  
1;;;"a55,a10";1;1 L;87  
2;25;1001;a4;;"1,5 L";
```

Comment: I managed to combine this with Maroun Maroun's answer to get what I needed. thanks!

Comment: What if a ; occurs in the quotes ?

Comment: This worked out of the box for me. No need to combine with something else.

Comment: is there some place where I can plug in a sed expression and have an human-readable (to non-users) explanation pop out?

Comment: @hek2mgl I just had to replace the quotes as well

Comment: @flyingsilverfin Ah ok. Missed that. Btw, IMHO the correct answer is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32498215/171318)

Comment: @９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９ Good question, the ; are actually turned into , !

Comment: @hek2mgl I'm inclined to agree this is just for testing right now. On production I might implement a proper parser

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a csv parser. Parsing csv with shell tools is hard (you will encounter regular expressions soon, and they rarely get **all** cases).

There is one in almost every language. I recommend [python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

You can also do this using excel/openoffice variants by opening the file and then saving with `;` as the separator.

Comment: I suppose that for some reason regexes are not capable implementing this kind of this robustly. I'll use python for production when correctness is important

Answer (score 0):

You can used `sed`:

```
echo '0,1000,89,"a1,a2,a3",33,,' | sed -e "s|\"||g"
```

This will replace `"` with the empty string (deletes it), and you can pipe another `sed` to replace the `,` with `;`:

```
sed -e "s|,|;|g"
```

---

```
$ echo '0,1000,89,"a1,a2,a3",33,,' | sed -e "s|\"||g" | sed -e "s|,|;|g"
>> 0;1000;89;a1;a2;a3;33;;
```

Note that you can use any separator you want instead of `|` inside the `sed` command. For example, you can rewrite the first `sed` as:

```
sed -e "s-\"--g"
```

Comment: you probably didn't catch my edit while you were writing your response - I need to replace the commas that are UNquoted, so that the ones that are quoted stay. Then the quotes need to be removed.

Comment: This [does not work](http://pastebin.com/qQ1tLa5e) for me. (I did not down-voted)